# perl system echo output redirection

Tags: perl, echo, system, io-redirection

The below code

```
system( echo hi there >>log.txt );
```

redirects correctly, but also prints the output to STDOUT.. so when I run my perl script I see

```
 perl script.pl
 hi there
```

and the log.txt file is updated correclty.

Question: how can I get it to only update the file and not STDOUT.

Note:
Please do not suggest using a file handle, I have reasons to make me not want to do that.

Comment: Your code isn't valid Perl (it's missing some quotes), so it won't run. Also, your script is probably doing something else, since `perl -E 'system("echo hi there >>log.txt");'` works as expected. Show use your real code if you want us to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the command using backticks:

```
`echo hi there >>log.txt`;
```

Then the result will not be printed to STDOUT, but returned, so you could store it in a variable. But you don't need to, you can also just ignore it.

Comment: actually that was my first appraoch, but for some reason, the .exe I am calling hangs sometimes when I call it using backticks, but does not when I do with system()..
anyway to do it with system()?

I might as well also only use backticks for the echo.. that might be a good solution..